# How can I fix a laptop battery that won't fully charge?

Tags: battery-life

The battery in my laptop (a Gateway EC13N01i) won't charge fully. The charge meter seems to be stuck at 92%. How can I fix this? Please provide step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Write a coherent question, first...

Comment: How old is the battery? It may have reached the end of it's life (especially if you predominantly keep it fully charged or there abouts)

Comment: I bought this 9 months ago. :(

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by one of three things:

1. Charging circuit error
2. Battery is dead/dying/old
3. Out of sync.

Fixes:

1. Hardware replacement needed - if in warranty try to ask the manufacturer. (Last resort, if the other two fail).
2. Buy a new battery (They typically have a much shorter life depending on how quick you use it. Average is 6 months on heavy usage, 12-18 months on lower usage).
3. Look for a option in BIOS or power control (if your laptop has a customised power program) that says "calibrate" or similar. If you can't find this, go in to the BIOS of your laptop (so the hard drive will not be working/no risk of damage), and simply leave it on until it turns off on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember posting this elsewhere in another post, but try these two cheap solutions first.

1. Bios battery.  For a battery that costs merely ~$2, you can solve a number of charging issues on laptops in which the laptop battery really isn't dead. Not sure why it works, but it does.
2. Could very well be the power module on the back of the laptop, where you connect the adapter.  Believe it or not, this module is usually removable from the motherboard of the laptop, and fairly cheap to replace.

I am just saying that these can assist in solving the problem, and if either one solves the issue, you are saving money over buying a new battery.

Comment: This answer about the `bios battery` helped me with a battery that wouldn't take any charge at all. Thanks